# Converting Range Statements to Sets in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to Extract the ranges of Variables from a Text File. I extracted lines of the forms 
X in 1..10
Y in 12..50
Z in 0..19 / 66/ 95..100
Where X in 1 ..10 states that X takes values from set 1 to 10
Similarly for Y and for Z its a Union of different ranges of the values (0 to 19, union 66,union 95 to 100)

I want to Map these Variables to their respective sets using Hashmap where Key is Variable name and value will be a Set. My Hashmap Signature is 
HashMap> hm=new HashMap>();

I am stuck at extracting the variables ranges from these plain strings. Can anyone help me here with their expertise?

Thanks,